# How to update assets data in deployed Angular project

Tags: python, angular, scripting

I am hosting an Angular project on a web server. On the server there are python scripts that are scheduled to run and generate a .json file. This .json saves over the existing .json in the projects assets file (dist/test/assets). 
When this occurs the .json is replaced but the data on the web page does not get updated.

Is there a way to get the project to update the data using a process similar to this?

Alternately, is there a way to pull the data directly from the server?
When this was tried the local project would not compile because it could not reach the server, but when the project is uploaded on the server it will need the correct file path

Answer (score 0):

You could query against the json file directly on the server.

```
this.http.get('server_url/test/assets/json_file.json').subscribe(
   data => {
      //do what you want with data in here.
   }
)
```

And to prevent your local server erroring, you could wrap the function call in `environment.production == true` or some such equivalent that prevent local.